# Jython: reducing color in half an image

Tags: jython

Im trying to reduce the red in an image in the lower half and i am stumped, this is the code i have come up with some far, just wondering if someone can point out why its not working for me?

```
def decreaseRed(pict):

width=getWidth(pict)
height=getHeight(pict)
canvas=makeEmptyPicture(width,height)
for x in range(0, width):
 for y in range(0, height/2):
  pixel = getPixel(pict,x,y)
  newRed = getRed(pixel)*0.5
  newGreen = getGreen(pixel)
  newBlue = getBlue(pixel)
  newColor = makeColor(newRed,newGreen,newBlue)
  pixelCanvas = getPixel(canvas,x,y)
  setColor(pixelCanvas,newColor)
  show(pict)
  show(canvas)

file=getMediaPath("testa.jpg")
pict=makePicture(file)

decreaseRed(pict)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe i have come to the answer, this will reduce the color red in the bottom half of an image to 70% of the original.

```
def decreaseRed(pict):

  width=getWidth(pict)
  height=getHeight(pict)
  canvas=makeEmptyPicture(width,height)
  for x in range(0, width):
    for y in range(0, height):
      pixel = getPixel(pict,x,y)
      newRed = getRed(pixel)
      newGreen = getGreen(pixel)
      newBlue = getBlue(pixel)
      newColor = makeColor(newRed,newGreen,newBlue)
      pixelCanvas = getPixel(canvas,x,y)
      setColor(pixelCanvas,newColor)
    for y in range(height/2,height):
      pixel = getPixel(pict,x,y)
      newRed = getRed(pixel)*0.7
      newGreen = getGreen(pixel)
      newBlue = getBlue(pixel)
      newColor = makeColor(newRed,newGreen,newBlue)
      pixelCanvas = getPixel(canvas,x,y)
      setColor(pixelCanvas,newColor)
  return canvas
file=getMediaPath("test.jpg")
pict=makePicture(file)

show(decreaseRed(pict))
```